# Can I force scrolling to end at certain points?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dDghx0g817LiskUnVLMA) in which I try to demo what I am doing with my project (warning requires flex-box). I have it so the bootstrap nav pill changes when I reach the header. The problem is scrolling appears to be chaotic (depending on screen size but also just randomly goes to different places with each scroll). So sometimes the section header is 10px from the top, others it is 50px. Is there a way I can manipulate the scroll using either CSS or JS?

**See Issue**

It will depend on browser, screen size and a variety of factors, however, if you scroll up and down some sections should get missed. This will only happen occasionally, but it does happen regularly.

**Code**

My Angular code for finding the offset...

```
 function elementInViewport(el) {
    var top = el.getBoundingClientRect().top - 90;
    return (
      top >= 0 && top <= 20
    );
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider setting the `overflow` css of your `body` element to `hidden` and the height to whatever you want the user to be able to scroll. I don't know why you'd want to do this, though.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am trying to ask. Given my code the hit is only registered if scrolling comes within 20px of the div's offset. If you scroll all the way down and all the way back up again (depending on screen resolution) you should see section 2 get missed. This isn't about not being able to scroll. And say I took your approach, how would I have multiple sections?